# Run a program automatically on script start-up

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make an AHK script open another program everytime it is started. The problem is, I don't want this to happen if that other program is already opened.

Here's what **seems to be supposed** to be working, but isn't : (this section is placed at the very top of my script)

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinNotExist, Microsoft Excel - myExcelFile.xls
Run C:\myExcelFile.xls
#IfWinExist
;REST OF MY SCRIPT GOES HERE
```

What **should** be happening :

If the window "Microsoft Excel - myExcelFile.xls" is not opened, run it. If not, do not.

What **is** happening :

Whether it is opened or not, it will try to run it again.

Comment: I generally recommend reading the [docs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/) before asking a question on SO. There, you will read that *#IfWinNotExist creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings.* You are looking for [IfWinNotExist](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/IfWinExist.htm), without the **#** at the beginning, which *checks if a matching window exists*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah, even though I had read the documentation, I had understood that the difference between `#IfWin` and `IfWin` was whether they were used inside or out of a specific hotkey. To my understanding, "creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings" also included "context-sensitive *auto-execution*" (when code is not inside a hotkey)

Indeed I was wrong and the solution is to remove the `#`.

Comment: Directives in AHK (things that start with a `#`) can't work that way. They are evaluated when the script starts and the rest of the execution flow can't be influenced by them. If you want to learn more about `#If...`, check out [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20538128/1282023).